# Objective C checkmark row on viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a setting screen that is a `UITableView` with rows of settings. When user open that screen I load stored settings and filled to `UITextField` etc... Everything was fine.

But there are some of the checkmark settings, I've been trying to check this in programmatically way but is not work, here is my code:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self LoadCurrentRecord];

    if(_previousValid)
    {
        NSIndexPath *regionFromData = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_regionAutoCheck inSection:3];
        [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:regionFromData].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

In fact, I can see data can load by check to this category but I didn't see checkmark icon.

Any idea?

Comment: check this condition in cellforrowatindexpath

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik can you point me to any example?

Comment: Not related, but you should always call `super` when overriding a method -> `[super viewDidAppear: animated]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've found a really simple solution for this case.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row == _regionAutoCheck && indexPath.section == 3)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else{
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone; // for other cases remove it
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

After that, add `[self.tableView reloadData];` into `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` and you will see it works.

That's all.

Thanks all for help

Answer (score 0):

You must need to set it in this method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  UITableViewCell *cell; // Create Cell
 if(_previousValid && indexPath.row == _regionAutoCheck && indexPath.section == 3 )
 {
 // SET  CHECKMARK
 } else {
 // SET NONE
 }
}
```

Comment: It's not work, `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView (<UITableView: 0x79d7fc00; frame = (0 0; 320 480); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x79261940>; layer = <CALayer: 0x79262ad0>; contentOffset: {0, -64}; contentSize: {320, 983}>) failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource`

Comment: I don't want to create new cell, I've just wanted to update old cell by cell indexPath

Comment: it is just example  you just need to reload tableview and set  check mark to  old cell

Comment: I have done this but have other problem. Because my cell is grouped and static cell, so when I apply `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, my all data in all others cell have gone, how can I fix that?

Comment: make sure you have objets in array and debug code and remove your code in **viewDidAppear** for reload tableview

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you should work with table- and collectionViews:

1. **Have a collection of dedicated data-elements for each of which a cell will be used to display its data.** In your case this would be some kind of Region object.
2. Implement the table/collectionview datasource methods that return number of cells in section and number of sections based on that collection.
3. Make sure you configure each cell **ONLY** in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` / `-collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`, just like PKT's answer. This cell might be reused, so assume any changes you made to this *type* of cell you need to update here.
4. When data changes, create an indexPath for the object that changes based on its position in the collection from 1. Then call '-reloadRowAtIndexPath:'/ `-reloadItemAtIndexPath` for that object. This will cause the tableView/collectionView to call `-tableViewcellForRowAtIndexPath:`/-`collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:' again. As this method now contains the logic for configuring the cell based on your data-object, everything is in sync.

I can't stress enough how important **1.** is. Simplest example is: each section is an array of data objects. If you have multiple sections, you can add each array to another array:

```
// one section:
NSArray *myData =     
    @[
        @[dataItem1, dataItem2, dataItem3]
        @[dataItem4, dataItem5, dataItem6]
     ];

- (NSUInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView: (UITableView *) tableView
{
    return myData.count;
}
- (NSUInteger) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView numnberOfRowsInSection: (NSUInteger) section
{
    NSArray *dataForSection = myData[section];
    return dataForSection.count;
}
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath:
{
    NSArray *dataForSection = myData[indexPath.section];
    MyObject *dataObject = dataForSection[indexPath.row];

    NSString * cellID = @"myCellID";
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cellID];
    if (nil == cell)
    {
        // create a cell
        // ...
    }

    // configure the cell based on the data object
    if (dataObject.isBlue)
    {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
    else
    {
        // N.B.! don't forget the else clause, as cells are reused, so this
        // cell might be recycled from a cell that was used to display
        // the data of a blue data object before.
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
return cell;
```

}

Comment: My data changes fine, but checkmark icon is not show even I `reloadData` or `beginsUpdate`